# CFCalendar returns unexpected values when switching between different regions in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

CFCalendar returns unexpected values when switching the region between India and Egypt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using the following code,..

```
if (CFCalendarGetFirstWeekday(_cal) == 2) { // Monday is first day of week

    return [_dayNames objectAtIndex:(dayOfWeek+1)%7];

}else if (CFCalendarGetFirstWeekday(_cal) == 7) { //saturday is first day of week

    return [_dayNames objectAtIndex:(dayOfWeek+6)%7];

}else {
    return [_dayNames objectAtIndex:dayOfWeek]; // Sunday is first day of week
}
```